# Spring Kafka Streams - Create Stream vs Inject an existing Stream bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams

I'm creating a Spring based service with Kafka Streams and noticed for a big consuming time difference when I'm using an existing @Bean KStream VS creating a stream for that stream.

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
@Autowired
private StreamsBuilder eventsStreamsBuilder;

@Bean("eventsKStream")
public KStream<String, String> eventsKStream() {

   KStream<String, String> stream = eventsStreamsBuilder.stream(...);
   stream.to("NEW_TOPIC");
   return stream;
}

// 1. First approach, create a stream for the "NEW_TOPIC" and filter it
@Bean("eventsFilterKStream")
public KStream<String, String> eventsFilterKStream() {
   return eventsStreamsBuilder.stream("NEW_TOPIC",....)
   .filter()
}

// 2. Second approach, inject the existing Stream Bean and filter it
@Bean("eventsFilterKStream")
public KStream<String, String> eventsFilterKStream(@Qualifier("eventsKStream") KStream<String, String> eventsKStream) {
   return eventsKStream.filter(...);
}
```

I have a consumer, using the console consumer... and noticed that for the first approach, it takes few sec for the data to arrive, But in the second approach, I'm getting the filtered data immediately!

Can you please explain me what is the difference? 
Why the first approache takes a few seconds for the message to arrive to the consumer?
What is the best approach ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Approach #2 is faster because it's adding a filter processor node to an existing `KStream`, as opposed to creating an entirely new `KStream` reading from a source topic in approach #1.

It depends on your topology, but I'd start with #2 unless you have a strong reason not to.

Comment: Is it reasonable to have a few sec latency between the first and the second approach?
I mean, I simply filtered the records to a NEW_TOPIC, then opened a KStream for the NEW_TOPIC and expected that it will be super quick...
But, probably I was wrong, still.. I don't understand why this is so slow.